# Config file changes were lost in WPF when new user opens the application

Tags: c#, wpf

All,

We have added custom configuration files to our WPF application. After installing the MSI (prepared with VS2010 setup template) we made changes to the configuration files. When a new user opens the application for the first time all the configuration file changes were lost.

Do i need to change settings while preparing MSI to avoid this or is this a server (2008 R2) specific?

Did any one come across this issue?

I really appreciate your help

Comment: So you're saying that you created custom app.config file and when new user installs your MSI, and opens WPF application, it overrides your app.config?

Comment: I have created APP_DATA folder and added config xml files to this folder. After Installing the MSI I have changed one of the xml files and everything worked as intended for me. When a new user opens the application for the first time in the same machine with different session, the changes to that xml were lost and reverted back to install time file. Am I clear now?